# 1.5 ton refrigeration compressor overheating

Tags: hvac, refrigerator

I have tried to design a glycol chiller where I want to achieve -5°Celsius. The compressor is 1.5 to and used 50 mfd capacitor with PSR connection. The 2 capillaries I have used are 5 feet each. Also, the refrigerant is **R32** and it's at**110PSI** on running mode.

The problem occurs when I run the machine, the cooling occurs at the evaporator side. But the compressor body temperature increases above 80°Celsius. Also, I have noticed when the water/glycol solution cooled down to 10°Celsius, some ice forms on the suction line of compressor.

The compressor model is  GMCC - **KSG175S!VKP**
visualize test model -

Please suggest what I need to change in the design to make it ready for proper chilling application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm… what is it about those photos that makes me think you're not licensed to handle R32…?

Comment: I understand your question @Tetsujin. But the legal stuff is bit different in the country that i am in and i have the legal rights and all safety stuff for experimenting both flammable  and non flammable refrigerant ...

Comment: I dunno, but perhaps removing the plastic wrap from the condenser to enable air flow would help?

Comment: @Martin plastic wrap is not part of the system. But yes i think air flow is the one which need to be increased...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a specialist/hobby project and thus off-topic as defined in the Help Center.

Comment: Is this really a home improvement question?

Comment: if this is considered off-topic here, a different possibly relevant (check its Help Center first) site would be https://engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay guys. thanks for support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue most likely, is the result of not enough air flow through the condenser.

You may need a bigger fan, but first make some modifications.

The fan is too far away from the condenser. Also, it needs to be shrouded to funnel the air it is drawing through the condenser and not around it.
( look under the hood of any automobile with an internal combustion engine.)

You may have air in the system also. When compressed it heats up.
The system needs to be under vacuum for at least 30 min. prior to adding the R32.

Ice on the suction line is normal in that situation.

Comment: yes, i did vacuum before charging as per the guideline...

Comment: Hi @RMDman, actually here air flow is towards the condenser coil. Its not blowing air as AC do. In this design do i need shrouded or funnel structure ?

Comment: Yes, the air is not being directed to the condenser.  There is too much space that allows air loss around the condenser.